# TSQL - Use Except Clause to return column differences between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Im using a very simple script to return the differences between two tables, 'TableA' and a duplicate copy of TableA named 'CopyOfTableA':

```
SELECT TableId, Column1, Column2 FROM CopyOfTableA
EXCEPT
SELECT TableId, Column1, Column2 FROM TableA
```

This will subtract the differences between the CopyOfTableA table and TableA and return only those rows that contain differences.

This works fine and returns the rows that contain differences but my requirement is to return the rows that are different but only populate the columns that contain the differences 
**so that I can see immediately where the differences are between rows.**

Comment: Only thing I can think of is a full join and compare columns individually.

Comment: Thanks Jayvee, do you have an example of your solution and ill give it a try? when you say compare columns individually what operator would I use for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something on these lines:

```
select case when isnull(a.TableId,0)<>isnull(b.TableId,0) then 'Difference' else 'OK' end as TableIdCompare,
    case when isnull(a.column1,'')<>isnull(b.Column1,'') then 'Difference...' else 'OK' as Column1Compare,
    case when isnull(a.column2,'')<>isnull(b.Column2,'') then 'Difference...' else 'OK' as Column2Compare,
from CopyOfTableA a
full join TableA b
```

Please notice that when a row is missing it will show all the columns as differences. Also, you can tailor the case statements to be a bit more informational by adding the values on both tables, etc.

Comment: Should 'From CopyOfTableA b' be aliased as A instead of B?

Comment: Also, how performant would this solution be on a table with a couple million rows? Would a full join add extra overhead to the script execution?

Comment: I amended the query thanks. And yes, it will be a lot more expensive the full join than the set based except. Depending on the number of column you can also try excepting Key, Column one by one and union the results

Comment: thanks Jayvee, im going to look at ways of cutting down the query using the except clause also so that the join is on a much smaller dataset.

Comment: yes, that's a good idea; first the except (or 2 excepts if you need it both ways) and then the full join to find the columns with differences.